# Migrate from MurmurHash to MurmurHash3

Tags: scala, hash, murmurhash

In Scala 2.10, `MurmurHash` for some reason is deprecated, saying I should use `MurmurHash3` now. But the API is different, and there is no useful scaladocs for `MurmurHash3` -> fail.

For instance, current code:

```
trait Foo {
  type Bar
  def id: Int
  def path: Bar

  override def hashCode = {
    import util.MurmurHash._
    var h = startHash(2)
    val c = startMagicA
    val k = startMagicB
    h = extendHash(h, id, c, k)
    h = extendHash(h, path.##, nextMagicA(c), nextMagicB(k))
    finalizeHash(h)
  }
}
```

How would I do this using `MurmurHash3` instead? This needs to be a fast operation, preferably without allocations, so I do not want to construct a `Product`, `Seq`, `Array[Byte]` or whathever `MurmurHash3` seems to be offering me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [MurmurHash3 algorithm](http://code.google.com/p/smhasher/) was changed, confusingly, from an algorithm that mixed in its own salt, essentially (`c` and `k`), to one that just does more bit-mixing.  The basic operation is now `mix`, which you should fold over all your values, after which you should `finalizeHash` (the `Int` argument for length is for convenience also, to help with distinguishing collections of different length).  If you want to replace your last `mix` by `mixLast`, it's a little faster and removes redundancy with `finalizeHash`.  If it takes you too long to detect what the last mix is, just `mix`.

Typically for a collection you'll want to mix in an extra value to indicate what type of collection it is.

So minimally you'd have

```
override def hashCode = finalizeHash(mixLast(id, path.##), 0)
```

and "typically" you'd

```
// Pick any string or number that suits you, put in companion object
val fooSeed = MurmurHash3.stringHash("classOf[Foo]")   

// I guess "id" plus "path" is two things?
override def hashCode = finalizeHash(mixLast( mix(fooSeed,id), path.## ), 2)
```

Note that the length field is NOT there to give a high-quality hash that mixes in that number.  All mixing of important hash values should be done with `mix`.

Comment: Thanks, Rex. The seed generation makes sense. For so `Product` this would be probably `stringHash(productPrefix)`.

Comment: @0__ - That would be a reasonable value.  It really boils down to what might be around with the same contents but a different identity; if no such thing exists (or you don't mind colliding with it/them) then you can put anything or nothing there.  "Only collide with things of the same name and contents (that are also a `Product` and have chosen a seed using the same obvious method)" is a very reasonable policy.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0/src/library/scala/util/hashing/MurmurHash3.scala) of MurmurHash3 suggests something like this:

```
override def hashCode = {
  import util.hashing.MurmurHash3._

  val h = symmetricSeed // I'm not sure which seed to use here
  val h1 = mix(h, id)
  val h2 = mixLast(h1, path ##)
  finalizeHash(h2, 2)
}
```

or, in (almost) one line:

```
import util.hashing.MurmurHash3._
override def hashCode = finalizeHash(mix(mix(symmetricSeed, id), path ##), 2)
```

Comment: Looks good. I guess I'll use `productSeed` as my original code was based on the product hash generator for arity 2.